# Does Excess Kurtosis Signal Non-Ergodicity?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, ensemble-learning, ergodic

I have been reading a lot about ergodicity and the main principle behind it seems pretty simple actually.

Based on my understanding, something is ergodic if the time average and the ensemble average are the same, or in other words.

This definition of it makes me think of kurtosis. Specifically in that, one could say a distribution is gaussian or normal, if the median (observed/time average) matches the mean(ensemble/calculated average) or the excess kurtosis is 0.

Does this mean that, if a distribution has significant skew in either direction so that the mean and median are drastically different and there is a significant amount of excess or deficit kurtosis, the distribution is non-ergodic?

Is this a correct understanding of the idea, and how it relates to other statistical metrics (mainly kurtosis) that can be used to highlight how what we observe in the sample can be different than what the sample calculates?

Answer (score 0):

No, these are different concept.

Median and mean give us information on the distribution of a random variable or process *on the same dimension*.

Ergodicity means that measuring a rv across different dimension will yield the same results regardless of the dimension we are looking at.

In the simplest terms, it means that, over time the random process will eventually reach /take all possible values.

Comment: I see what you mean about how the median and mean exist on the same timeline or path so you couldn't draw an ensemble conclusion from a singular path. This is interesting. It intuitively feels the same though as they imply the same thing (assuming they are different, just like the time and ensemble averages), mainly that what we observe as individuals are different from what the collection of our observations shows, regarding an average value. I thought in the simplest terms, it means that both the ensemble and the time averages will converge to the same point as samples for each increase?

Comment: But crucially, median and mean convey different information about the typical/frequent behavior of the distribution. 

Time average and spatial average are the same measure along different dimensions. Ergodicity means that these two averages will be the same, eventually. Crucially, this implies something important about the process: that there is no restriction on where the process can go over time and that eventually there is no particular role of time in the values the process generates (meaning the process cannot get stuck in some region).

Comment: Think of a simple example where there are a few states: -1, 0, 1 for the process to be in. As an ensemble, or in equilibrium, let's say these three values are equally likely, and so the average is zero. Now, for whatever rule you can cook up for a transition over time across these states, if the time average has to be the same as the ensamble average it means that we must pass through all the states (clearly, if we only visit a subset of them the average cannot, in general be zero) and we must do so in a way that visits all the states in the same proportion as the ensamble average.

Comment: Thanks for chatting about this! I really appreciate it! I understand what you are saying, I am just wondering how that insight is any different that what you would get from the kurtosis value. If it was was 0, this means the median and mean are the same, and that it’s a true Gaussian distribution (drunkard) so it will eventually visit and revisit all sample spaces as a drunk man will eventually get home. Maybe they point to the same thing but do it different ways, and I am not understanding the differences?

Comment: The key difference is in the definition. Ergodicity: same measure on different dimension has the same value. Mean/Median/Kurtosis: measure of a different thing on the same dimension.

Comment: I was thinking about this more and I could be wrong but I think the mean and median do in fact measure 2 different dimensions (time and space) as well because of how they are calculated. The mean looks at all the observations through the lens of space to get the average distance or value (the average can be totally devoid from the observed values), while the median measures just the observations through time, showing what observation we are actually likely to see on anyone path or event in time. Is this totally illogical thinking or does this kind of make sense?

Comment: Sorry, but no. Mean takes all value of a distribution, weight those values by their probability and adds them up. Large weights tell us that value is more likely and so we end up with a value in the support of that distribution which should representative of the typical value (according to this particular way of measuring how typical a value is). The median uses the relative position of a value in the support as a criterion to generate a point, again, in the support. So, both are looking to the support to output another number within the support. Which number depends on the probabilities.